# Trying to iterate through elements based on $(this) element w/ jQuery only for checked rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have multiple rows like this created dynamically:

```
<tr class="row">
    <td class="row-checkbox-delete-row"><input tabindex="-1" class="checkbox-delete-row" type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td class="row-target">10</td>
    <td class="row-product-id"><input class="id-target row-product-id" name="lineItem[0].originalInput" type="text" data-ajax-line-id="1" /></td>
    <td class="row-qty"><input class="qty-target row-qty" name="lineItem[0].quantity" type="text" value="1" /></td>
    <td class="row-description"></td>
    <td class="row-abc6"></td>
    <td class="row-abc8"><input readonly tabindex="-1" class="abc8-target row-abc8" name="lineItem[0].abc8" type="text" /></td>
    <td class="row-upc"></td>
    <td class="row-ndc"></td>
</tr>
```

I want to iterate through all of them and grab the attribute `data-ajax-line-id` from each one.

I have this code but it's not working. Need some help.

```
var lineids = new Array();

$(".checkbox-delete-row:checked").each(function() {
    lineids.push($(this).parents("td").siblings(".row-product-id").children(".id-target").attr("data-ajax-line-id"));
});
```

Comment: Define `not working`. Errors on the console?

Comment: You're looking in `td.row-product-id` but the `data-ajax-line-id` attribute is on the other input field in `td.row-abc8`

Comment: They are being added dynamically.

Comment: First of all, you don't have any checked boxes, so you have to run this on an event where the boxes are checked. Secondly, you have a readonly attribute that should be at the end of the input, not in the middle of the other atttributes, or you should assign it a value. Thirdly, the only element that has such a data attribute has nothing to do with the elements you're targeting, it's not inside an element with the class `.row-product-id`, and lastly, it won't work.

Comment: In my test env I do have it running from a button that is looking at the checked boxes...

Comment: I did, and didn't get the answer I wanted.... see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149141/trying-to-generate-an-array-from-jquery-checked-selector

Comment: I just tested your code with a basic jsfiddle and it seems to work but you have wrap it in a table and a tbody otherwise the parent of the input is the 'body' which obviously then finds nothing with the other selectors. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/e9MQ6/

Answer (score 2):

Then iterate over the rows, check if the `.checkbox-delete-row` is checked in that row, and if it is, get the data attribute from that row and add it to the array, if not just return null :

```
var arr = $.map($('.row'), function(el) { 
    return $('.checkbox-delete-row', el).is(':checked') ? 
         $('[data-ajax-line-id]', el).data('ajax-line-id') :
         null; 
});
```

Comment: yeah, this is cleaner.